# cannot display image by setting State

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I'm trying to display my pics by setting the **const [pics, setPics] = useState([])**. In the **searchPhotos** function, i don't know how to set the state of **setPics** to the result that i got from the API key. I had the error as  "**Line 25:25:  'results' is not defined  no-undef**". Please help me to fix my problem! Thank you so much!

SearchPhotos.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { createApi } from "unsplash-js";

export default function SearchPhotos() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [pics, setPics] = useState([]);

  const unsplash = createApi({
    accessKey: "//my key",
  });

  const searchPhotos = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    unsplash.search
      .getPhotos({
        query: query,
      })
      .then((result) => {
        setPics(results);
      });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <form className="form" onSubmit={searchPhotos}>
        <label className="label" htmlFor="query">
          {" "}
          {" "}
        </label>{" "}
        <input
          type="text"
          name="query"
          value={query}
          onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
          className="input"
          placeholder={`Try "dog" or "apple"`}
        />{" "}
        <button type="submit" className="button">
          Search{" "}
        </button>{" "}
      </form>
      <div className="card-list">
        {" "}
        {pics.map((pic) => {
          return (
            <div className="card" key={pic.id}>
              <img
                className="card--image"
                alt={pic.alt_description}
                src={pic.urls.full}
                width="50%"
                height="50%"
              ></img>{" "}
            </div>
          );
        })}{" "}
      </div>{" "}
    </>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that you have a typo: `then((result)`  but  `setPics(results);` (plural)

Comment: I corected it and then i got the eror "pics.map is not a function" ...

Comment: How does `results` look like? What is its type? I presume not an array as it would have `map` function defined?

Comment: try optional chaining. i.e ```pics?.map```

Comment: @Dario i updated my question. You can check!

Comment: if pics looks like your log, you need `.then((response) => { setPics(response.results);      }); `

Comment: well, it says "response is not defined"....

Comment: then you are not getting any data in the callback; use the debugger to see what values you get in `then`;